# Is there a name and/or notation for arbitrary sum of sums?

Tags: notation, summation

I am looking for information about sums of the form:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i f(j)$$

But not just that form, but arbitrarily many stacked sums.  Even just a name would help.  To be specific about what I mean, I have been using the following definition:

$$(\sum_{i=a}^b)^1f(i) := \sum_{i=a}^bf(i)$$
$$(\sum_{i=a}^b)^xf(i) := \sum_{i=a}^b (\sum_{j=a}^i)^{x-1} f(j)$$

I am particularly interested in:

$$f_x(n) = (\sum_{i=1}^n)^x1$$

Any pointers to information on any of these ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Including a name for this, better notation, any interesting solutions involving these sums etc.

Comment: Many people would write that first sum as $$\sum_{1\le j\le i\le n} f(i).$$This easily generalizes to multiple sums.

Comment: Double or nested sum$[$mation$]$ ?

Comment: Sometimes people describe the shape made by the summation indices summed over (when graphed on an integer lattice), such as saying "the summation over the triangular region ..." For examples, google together the phrases "double summation" and "triangular region". To not be ambiguous, this terminology assumes absolute convergence over the summation region, however.

Comment: @MJD So he wants to study $\displaystyle f_x(n)=\sum_{1\le t_1\le\dots\le t_x\le n}1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a name for those sums, but I surely know you can calculate them easily:

$$
(\sum_{i=a}^b)^xf(i) = \sum_{i=a}^b\binom{b-i+x-1}{x-1}f(i)
$$

It's a double counting obtained from the question "how many time I add $f(i)$?".

In fact, if you have x variables $i=i_1\le i_2\le i_3\le \dots \le i_x$, you have an addend $f(i)$ for all choices of the values of the variables distinct from $i$.

So you have to count the number of ordinated $(x-1)$-uples of integers between $i$ and $b$.

It's a well-known formula (there's in every combinatoric book you may find), that the number of those is

$$
\binom{b-i+x-1}{x-1}
$$
So you have the desired coefficients.

In particular,

$$
(\sum_{i=a}^b)^x1 = \sum_{i=a}^b\binom{b-i+x-1}{x-1}=\binom{b-a+x}{x}
$$

Comment: Awesome, it looks like it works!  I was trying to figure out exactly that (how many times I add f(i)) but I did not see it.  Could you get me started so I can see exactly how to work that out?

Comment: That's a combinatorical count. (wait for it, I'm editing)